# SQL Query to get a boolean value from a BIT type column

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, boolean

I am facing a problem getting the `boolean` value from one of the `columns` of my database. I am using `SQL Server 2008` where in I have created a `database`as follows:

Table name:  `SysUser3` and columns as:

ProductName      ||    ProductId        ||        SelectedProducts

The column `SelectedProducts` is a `BIT` type column and contains `False` values for each of the row entries at present.

Now, I am writing a `SQL Query` to get the boolean value from my 'SelectedProducts' column

Here is my code:

```
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;User Instance=true"))
        {
            con.Open();

            string cmdString = "SELECT ProductName,SelectedProducts FROM SysUser3";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dataRead = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dataRead.Read())
                    {
                        items.Add(new ProductModel
                        {
                            Selected=(bool)dataRead["SelectedProducts"];
                            ProductName= dataRead["ProductName"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am getting an error at this line and hence not able to run the code:

> Selected=(bool)dataRead["SelectedProducts"];

Am I doing it correctly ? can someone tell me what's wrong in the code?

Comment: The error message suggests that there are "syntax errors" on that very line that I have mentioned above plus the following line of ProductName=....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a semicolon misplaced. Change it to a comma.
It should read:

```
                while (dataRead.Read())
                {
                    items.Add(new ProductModel()
                    {
                        Selected=(bool)dataRead["SelectedProducts"],
                        ProductName= dataRead["ProductName"].ToString()
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try `GetBoolean(column_odrinal)` method.

```
  if(!dataRead.IsDBNull(1))
     Selected=dataRead.GetBoolean(1);
```

OR you may fix it if return value if null.

```
Selected =  (dataRead["SelectedProducts"] as bool?) ??  false ;
```

Comment: In this case, you know the ordinal position of the column is 1, but if you wanted to get it by column name, use GetOrdinal(). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal.aspx